# pass openpyxl data to pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am splitting "full name" fields into "first name", middle name" and "last name" fields from data from an excel file. I couldn't figure out how to do that in pandas, so I turned to openpyxl. I got the variables split as I desired. But, [since adding columns to openpyxl for the new fields is not easy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/wHGecdQg3Iw), I thought I would pass the values to pandas.

I'm generating the dataframe that I need when I run the code, but once I send the df to ExcelWriter, only the last row is added to the Excel file. The data is in the right places, though.

Here's the code:

```
for cellObj in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
    #print cellObj
    id = sheet['A' + str(cellObj)].value
    fullname = sheet['B' + str(cellObj)].value.strip()
    namelist = fullname.split(' ')  
    for i in namelist:
        firstname = namelist[0]
        if len(namelist) == 2:
            lastname = namelist[1]
            middlename = ''
        elif len(namelist) == 3:
            middlename = namelist[1]
            lastname = namelist[2]
        elif len(namelist) == 4:
            middlename = namelist[1]
            lastname = namelist[2] + " " + namelist[3]
        if (namelist[1] == 'Del') | (namelist[1] == 'El') | (namelist[1] == 'Van'):
            middlename = ''
            lastname = namelist[1] + " " + namelist[2]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'personID':id,'lastName':lastname,'firstName':firstname,'middleName':middlename}, index=[id])

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', columns=['ID','lastName','firstName','middleName'])
    writer.save()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things. First, your code is only ever going to get you one line, because you overwrite the values every time it passes an if test. for example,

```
  if len(namelist) == 2:
        lastname = namelist[1]
```

This assigns a string to the variable `lastname`. You are not appending to a list, you are just assigning a string. Then when you make your dataframe,
`df = pd.DataFrame({'personID':id,'lastName':lastname,...` your using this value, so the dataframe will only ever hold that string. Make sense? If you must do this using openpyexcel, try something like:

```
lastname = [] #create an empty list
if len(namelist) == 2:
    lastname.append(namelist[1]) #add the name to the list
```

However, I think your life will ultimately be much easier if you just figure out how to do this with pandas. It is in fact quite easy. Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
#read excel
df = pd.read_excel('myInputFilename.xlsx', encoding = 'utf8')
#write to excel
df.to_excel('MyOutputFile.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I forgot to append to a list. The part in pandas I had trouble with was splitting the name fields into 3, which was easier in openpyxl

Comment: I was using pd.read_excel, but it doesn't interpret the formulas, this is not a very good solution for reading xlsx

Answer (score 3):

FWIW openpyxl 2.4 makes it pretty easy to convert all or part of an Excel sheet to a Pandas Dataframe: `ws.values` is an iterator for all that values in the sheet. It also has a new `ws.iter_cols()` method that will allow you to work directly with columns.

It's currently (April 2016) available as an alpha version and can be installed using `pip install -U --pre openpyxl`

The code would then look a bit like this:

```
sheet["B1"] = "firstName"
sheet["C1"] = "middleName"
sheet["D1"] = "lastName"

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=2):
    id_cell, name = row

    fullname = name.value.strip()
    namelist = fullname.split()
    firstname = namelist[0]
    lastname = namelist[-1]
    middlename = ""
    if len(namelist) >= 3:
        middlename = namelist[1]
    if len(namelist) == 4:
        lastname = " ".join(namelist[-2:])
    if middlename in ('Del', 'El', 'Van', 'Da'):
        lastname = " ".join([middlename, lastname])
        middlename = None

    name.value = firstname
    name.offset(column=1).value = middlename
    name.offset(column=2).value = lastname

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: I had found ws.values, but it wasn't working. I thought I had the right version of openpxl, but based on your explanation I'm sure I didn't.

Comment: You'll need to use an alpha version of the library to get `ws.values` but as the code shows, it doesn't seem necessary for your task.

Comment: I updated openpyxl and used ws.values because this code will be part of other pandas-based code.

Comment: Best double check you're using 2.4 alpha. You might also want to work with a checkout. See docs on how to do that.