# openpyxl read out excel table and pass it to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings, listobject

I would like to read the content of excel tables (*) into pandas DataFrames with xlwings.

I know about: [pass openpyxl data to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655525/pass-openpyxl-data-to-pandas)
and about: 
openpyxl.worksheet.table module

Such module provides a bunch of functionality for creating & modifying excel tables but I can not figure out how to simply pass the table into a DataFrame, nor do I know if that is actually possible (i.e. I don't think there is a method to read xlwings object into Pandas)

Any idea?

NOTES:
1) Please be aware that I am talking about tables NOT sheets.(I know about pd.read_excel('name.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')

2) I know as well that a way around is skipping rows or columns when reading a sheet, that would not make it in my case. I need to refer to a named table.

3) There is often a missunderstanding of what a table is in Excel for non excel-users. A table is a named ranged (you can go to INSERT tab and you see "Table"). That object is refered in VBA as Listobject. So a table is not a simple range in excel, nor a named range, it is more than that, it is actually the excel version of the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Basically like @Max Kaha's answer below, but use the table name in the range: `df = sht.range('MyTable').options(pd.DataFrame).value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Builtin Converters of the xlwings module ? They seem to have prebuilt functions to convert to a [Pandas DataFrame](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#pandas-dataframe-converter) as well as a [Pandas Series](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#pandas-series-converter).

[xlwings Documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#built-in-converters)

Here is the quick example they give:

```
>>> sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
>>> df = sht.range('A1:D5').options(pd.DataFrame, header=2).value
>>> df
    a     b
    c  d  e
ix
10  1  2  3
20  4  5  6
30  7  8  9
```

Comment: Hi Max, congrats for being a new contributor. regarding the answer I did not try that but is looks like it passes to a dataframe a particular range of a sheet. What I am talking about here is passing a table of a sheet. A table is a named ranged, so called Listobject in VBA code.